# How to catch Javascript:void(0)

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, window, void

I wrote this script to pop-up a message any time a user clicks on an external link from our site. When I wrote this I assumed the best way to do this would be to check location.host and compare it to the url the user is attempting to visit.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        if (this.href.match(location.host)) {
            //alert('Please continue on to our site.');
            window.onbeforeunload = null;
        } 
        else {

            if (window.confirm('NOTICE: By accessing this link, you will be leaving the DBPR website. DBPR is not responsible for the content of the Internet website you are entering. DBPR neither warrants nor makes any representations nor endorsements as to the accuracy, quality, content or completeness of the information, text, images, graphics, hyperlinks, and other items contained on the Internet website you are entering. DBPR is not responsible or liable for any viruses or contaminations of your hardware, software, peripherals or property, resulting from use of the Internet websites linked to or from the DBPR Internet website. Do you want to proceed?')
){
    // They clicked Yes
}
else
{
    // They clicked no
    return false;
}
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

The way the code currently stands, it works in the majority of cases, however I noticed that a couple buttons on our home page reference javascript:void(0), and they cause the confirm box to prompt on click .

Is there a way you would recommend to treat javascript:void(0) as an internal link or completely diregard it?

Thanks,
TG

Comment: Can you give an example of one of the links?

Comment: ... `|| this.href.match(/^javascript:/i)`?

Comment: Why is `javascript:void(0)` (which should be `void 0`) being used at all? Why is the listener on links that don't need it? Test the link when attaching the listener and only add it to external links. If external links are considered harmful, why aren't users aware of external links *before* they click on them?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why javascript:void(0) is being used. I'm working on a site that was originally developed years ago and am just trying to add some more functionality to it until we get our new site live. Thanks for all of your recommendations

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
if (this.href.match(location.host) || 
    this.href.toLowerCase().indexOf('javascript') !== -1) {
        // allow
}
```